# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady does not fire in WKWebView in iOS application

Tags: swift, youtube, embed, wkwebview

Im trying to make sure an user has watched an entire YouTube video before moving to the next screen.

I got this design from another response in SO where I can see how much of the video was actually played. The problem is, I am only receiving notifications for the "##### Outside!" handler.

All other messages being sent dont work because ( I think) the **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady** function is never executed.

Here is a live example and works perfectly : http://jsfiddle.net/sg6zkrmp/

So I dont understand why its not working for me here.

```
   func setUpUI() {
        let js = """
            var player, timer, timeSpent = [], display = document.getElementById('display');

            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('API Ready!');
                player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
                    events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
                });
            }

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('a change occurred');
                if(event.data === 1) { // Started playing
                    if(!timeSpent.length){
                        for(var i=0, l=parseInt(player.getDuration()); i<l; i++) timeSpent.push(false);
                    }
                    timer = setInterval(record,100);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }

            function record(){
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('Recording!');
                timeSpent[ parseInt(player.getCurrentTime()) ] = true;
                showPercentage();
            }

            function showPercentage(){
                var percent = 0;
                for(var i=0, l=timeSpent.length; i<l; i++){
                    if(timeSpent[i]) percent++;
                }
                percent = Math.round(percent / timeSpent.length * 100);
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('Give me that percentage!!');
            }
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('##### Outside!');
        """
        let script = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webConfiguration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        webConfiguration.userContentController.add(self, name: "clickListener")
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.backgroundColor = .red

     .......

        let html = """
           <iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjB1OvEYMhY?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
           <p id="display"></p>
        """
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
    .......
       func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)
    {
        print("------> ", message.body)
    }
}
```

BTW, when the view loads, I can see the message printed several times instead of one :

```
------>  ##### Outside!
------>  ##### Outside!
------>  ##### Outside!
------>  ##### Outside!
------>  ##### Outside!
------>  ##### Outside!
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it for anyone interested. I just needed to add this to my html :

```
let html = """
           <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
           <iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DjB1OvEYMhY?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&playsinline=1"></iframe>
           <p id="display"></p>
        """
```

Now it works perfectly fine.